# Invalid file extension when uploading from Sharepoint

Tags: php, html, sharepoint, file-upload

I have a website up and running which makes use of file uploads. Everything is working fine, except for one of the users. They are using IE8 to upload files from their SharePoint server to the website. When I look at the $_FILES variable in PHP the 'name' key looks like this:

```
somefilename[1]
```

Instead of

```
somefilename.pdf
```

The uploads are then blocked, because the extension is not allowed. Has anyone ever dealt/seen this before? It looks like a temporary name, or a hidden file extension.

Edit:

Some of you requested the $_FILES variable:

```
[Filedata] => Array
    (
        [name] => Algemene%20Voorwaarden%20Corporate%20Services%202011[2]
        [type] => application/octet-stream
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phps19zye
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 148021
    )
```

This should be a PDF file. I need the extension, not only for security reasons, the [type] would be better suited for that, but also for presentation and functionality. I need to display the correct icon for a file type, and separate images for processing.

The HTML form is just a basic test form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="uploadtest3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
            <br /><input type="submit" value="Uploaden" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP file is the following:

```
$targetFolder = '/uploadtests/uploads3';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($_FILES);` and paste the output? It'd also be good to see the upload form's markup.

Comment: Do you absolutely require an extension? Can you heuristically sniff the file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

Have seen this issue before but am not sure what caused it.  I would not even like to call it an error because `some files extension can be intentionally removed or altered` for malicious purpose.

The most `important thing is validating file properly` and worry less if a file has extension or not

**Reasons :**

- `File Extension Can easily be faked` and it would be bad if your application relies on file extension only for validation
- `$_FILES ['file_upload']['type']` would return `application/octet-stream` for all files with not extension so it not not also a option for validation
- Since its a browser issue then its a `Client Related Problem` so you don't have any control. If you are able to manage this you would definitely increase user experience

### Simple Patch

The solution is very simple. All you need to validate your file with `FILEINFO` and fix any extension issue to your uploaded file.

You also need to validated all uploaded file based on their Mime Type ... and remove any invalid file.

**Prove of Concept**

```
$allowedTypes = array (
        "pdf" => "application/pdf" 
);

$pathFinal = "final";
$pathTemp = "temp";
try {
    if (! empty ( $_FILES )) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES ['file_upload'] ['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES ['file_upload'] ['name'];
        $destinationTemp = $pathTemp . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        $destinationFinal = $pathFinal . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        /**
         * Move To tempary File
         */
        move_uploaded_file ( $tempFile, $destinationTemp );

        $fileMime = mimeInfo ( $destinationTemp );
        $key = array_search ( $fileMime, $allowedTypes );

        /**
         * Validate Mime Type
         */
        if (empty ( $key )) {
            unlink ( $destinationTemp );
            throw new Exception ( "File Type not Supported" );
        }

        /**
         * Fix Extention Issues
         */
        $ext = pathinfo ( $destinationTemp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        if (empty ( $ext )) {
            $destinationFinal .= "." . $key;
        }

        /**
         * Transfer File to Original Location
         */
        copy ( $destinationTemp, $destinationFinal );
        unlink ( $destinationTemp );

        echo "OK";
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "ERROR :", $e->getMessage ();
}
```

**Function Used**

```
function mimeInfo($file) {
    return finfo_file ( finfo_open ( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ), $file );
}
```

Comment: This would probably be a very good solution, but unfortunately the server hasn't updated to PHP 5.3 yet, so I can't deploy this. However, the PHP function 'mime_content_type' is the PHP 5.2 alternative and does return mime type application/pdf, instead of octet-stream. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome .... i did not know you where using PHP 5.2 ..... good to know i was able to help

Answer (score 1):

`somefilename` appears to be an array. Are your users selecting more than one file to upload??  You need to limit the number of files allowed to upload, or catch the array and handle it properly. You might also ensure that Sharepoint is set to [allow multiple file uploads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/54fe06d5-caba-431c-8472-0b500e22f390).

Also, I found information regarding the way that [IE8 passes the file](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/07/27/uploading-a-file-using-fileupload-control-fails-in-ie8.aspx) upload to the server. The source article states:

> Additionally, the “Include local directory path when uploading files” URLAction has been set to "Disable" for the Internet Zone. This change prevents leakage of potentially sensitive local file-system information to the Internet. **For instance, rather than submitting the full path C:\users\ericlaw\documents\secret\image.png, Internet Explorer 8 will now submit only the filename image.png.**

This means, if your code (or Sharepoint) is looking to delimit the folder structure from filename by `PATH_SEP`, then with IE8 it will obviously fail.

Comment: It looks like an array, but the file gets uploaded just fine, just the filename is wrong. Also, I have no way to catch an array, file uploads do not allow arrays to be passed. I'll let the system administrators look into setting SharePoint to (dis)allow multiple file uploads.

The IE8 info doesn't really apply. I don't need the full path anyway, I don't think other browsers pass a full filename either.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the file type not by extension but by Mime type. Use the variable `$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]` to get the Mime type.

This way users cannot tamper with the extension with weird ASCII characters, and you know what file is what reliably.

Comment: See the additional info. I need the file extension for other reasons too.

Comment: @Bas You should check why's it's posting `application/octet-stream`, it should be `application/pdf`. If you can fix that your problem would be solved. It's very dangerous to rely on file extensions, it can really easily be tempered.